# how to deploy .war files in tomcat using ubuntu 14.04

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, ubuntu-14.04

I need some help,I have .war file ("NewGateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war"). I will deploy it into tomcat directory, this my tomcat path

```
/opt/tomcat/webapps
             |
             ---->docs
                 |
                  ---->
             ---->examples
                 |
                  ---->
             ---->host-manager
             ---->manager
             ---->NewGateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
                  |
                   ---->META-INF
                       |
                       ---->null
             ---->Root
             ---->NewGateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
```

I run this script on terminal :

```
#sudo /opt/tomcat/bin/starup.sh
```

tomcat running normally

```
belva@belva-Aspire-4741:/opt/tomcat/bin$ sudo ./startup.sh 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
Tomcat started.
belva@belva-Aspire-4741:/opt/tomcat/bin$
```

when I access through a browser with this url

```
localhost:8080/NewGateway-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/server/report
```

I getting 404,I not getting some logs.I run this way on windows but there is no problem,need your help ....

Comment: Why do you expect it to not give 404? Have you defined the resource?

Comment: Show us your catalina.out log file.

Comment: First of all, what happens when you access tomcat manager using this url: http://localhost:8080/manager/html

Comment: Somewhat unrelated to your question: Whatever you do, DO NOT RUN TOMCAT AS ROOT (e.g. vs. sudo). You don't want a server, potentially internet-reachable, to run with root permission. If you installed ubuntu's tomcat, it will run as daemon anyway. However, now that you did this, you'll need to fix the permissions on tomcat's directories: Best through uninstallation and reinstall.

Comment: when I access the url,I was asked to fill in the username and password for localhost